# How would you model 'a sphere with a shell' like object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, light

I am trying to model this thing, but the silver cover on top is what I have no idea how to go about.

And the blue-ish reflection I believe is from the sphere being cast on the inner side of the silver bits.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Just create your sphere and over it draw the shape of your cuts using a Bezier Curve object.

Adjust its shape as necessary, then use knife project to cut the shape.

[image: Bezier Curve]

In object mode select your curve, then without deselecting, select your sphere, by this specific order. Enter edit mode on the sphere and with all faces selected use *Knife Project* with the option *Cut Through* active.

[image]

Carefully select all the unwanted parts then remove them by deleting the faces.

[image: Final Sphere shell]