# How to model Yin Yang sphere?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a Yin Yang symbol in 3D like this: [Yin Yang mapped onto Torus - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayQ4IaAMr5Y)

[image: Yin Yang Torus]

But I can't find a way to make it with Blender. Any ideas?

FYI: I tried to create it from Quad Sphere like a tennis ball, but failed.

[image: Failed Yin Yang sphere]

Comment: Hello :). You can get there pretty easily using default UV sphere, half/circles and Knife-project tool. [Timestamp 0:21](https://youtu.be/ayQ4IaAMr5Y?t=21) shows the topology.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66942

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Jachym Michal and Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I made it!

[image: Yin Yang Animation]

You can download Blend File for free from
https://gum.co/yin_yang_sphere_blend

The procedure is as follows:

1. Add *UV Sphere* (Radius = `1m`)
2. Add *Plane* (Size = `sqrt(2)`, RotationX = `90`)
3. Select *Plane* -> *Convert to* -> *Curve from Mesh/Text*
4. Edit *Plane* -> Extrude vertex to make square with diagonal line (Turn on Vertex Snap mode)
5. Finish editing *Plane*
6. Select *Plane* then *UV Sphere*
7. Go into Edit mode -> *Knife Project* (Cut through = ON)

[image: Step 1-3]
Step 1-3

[image: Step 4-5]
Step 4-5

[image: Step 6-7]
Step 6-7

[image: Finish]
Assigned materials (white, black and transparent)

---

NOTE: If you look closely at the [reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayQ4IaAMr5Y), the inner surface of the sphere is slightly raised.

[image]

My model doesn't have that part, so if you set the camera to the angle where you can see the Yin Yang plane, a small circle will be distorted horizontally.

[image: My model is distorted]

Unfortunately, this seems to be the limit for non-mathematical modeling.