# How to find the yin yang plane?

Tags: modeling, animation, 3d-view, image, 2d

I followed the instructions given in the answer on how to make the yin yang sphere [How to model Yin Yang sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185976/how-to-model-yin-yang-sphere/186040#186040) and it worked pretty well but I can't get it to line up to make the shape. messing around with the angles I can get close but never lines upright as one side is always closer to the camera so there is more yin than yang or vise versa. Is there a way to line it up perfectly? or make it appear 2d like in the gif?

Comment: If one side being always closer to the camera is the issue, then perhaps you want orthographic mode? It's Numpad 5 or a setting in the camera depending if you want that in viewport or render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is to use an orthographic view. To do this, you can press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> for an orthographic viewport, or follow below instructions for an orthographic camera (for rendering).

To make your camera orthographic, select your camera, go to Object Data Properties, and in the **Type** dropdown, select Orthographic. That should help! If it did, please consider marking the question as accepted and upvoting.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly!

Comment: Awesome! Please press the checkmark next to the answer to show that it worked for you.